# GlusterFS with CIFS, quotas and LDAP

Tags: active-directory, cifs, openfiler, glusterfs

Has anyone had experience plugging GlusterFS and Openfiler together **or something similar**?

Here is the motivation:

- Disk space on multiple server regrouped using GlusterFS
- Centralized access using LDAP/AD and quota management using Openfiler as the GlusterFS client
- SMB/CIFS server for easy sharing to multiple users on Mac and Windows

I know I can have Gluster installed on Openfiler (rPath Linux) successfully but Openfiler seems to be very picky on what it can use as a shared drive. Mounting the Gluster volume inside an existing share does not seem to allow quotas with the mounted folder free space.

If this is not possible, is there any alternative to give the same capabilities?

Comment: Gluster Storage Platform has CIFS integration.  no need for OpenFiler

Comment: Does it have LDAP integration and quotas?

Comment: Gluster Storage Platform has CIFS integration but doesn't seem to have LDAP nor quotas. I need those features together. Any other recommendations?

Comment: GlusterFS does not support quota.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you could use ceph as your cluster file system, and export as smb, with ldap (well, I assume you can authenticate to ldap for Samba).

http://ceph.newdream.net/

Of course, that means btrfs (beta) and ceph (is it even beta?).

Have you checked on the Gluster mailing list? http://www.gluster.org/interact/mailinglists/

Ceph should work, assuming it works well enough.

Comment: Ceph is not an usable option for the years to come and the effort to setup the a ceph server is incredible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ronald though I've heard the same thing as pfo: ceph is sadly still too immature for production.